# Deploying Multi-Page React App on AWS S3 & Route 53

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-router, github-pages

Using this [great tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-deploy-a-reactjs-website-on-aws-s3-with-github-ci-f0519d120063), I was able to host my single page app on *name.com* (I created an S3 bucket with the build directory then made an Alias in Route 53 with my custom domain).

```
class App extends Component {   
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <LandingPage/>
        </div>
    );   
  } 
}
```

However, when I try to host the multi-page version of my app, I get a blank white screen. Following suggestions from other discussions, I changed Router to HashRouter and added basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL} - none of which worked.

```
import {
    HashRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage/>}/>
                <Route path="/menu" element={<MenuPage/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

I also tried changing homepage to various paths in package.json

- "homepage": ".",
- "homepage": "./",
- "homepage": "https://name.com"
- "homepage": "https://name.github.io",
- "homepage": "https://name.github.io/website",
- etc.

My other idea was to host my app on GitHub pages, then use Route 53 and CNAME. I was able to get my multi-page app running on name.github.io/website but once I tried to reroute name.com to name.github.io/website, name.com would just display a blank screen.

Any help or suggestions would really be appreciated!!! Thank you!

Comment: See if https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#s3-and-cloudfront helps at all.